# Why is ping working when all incoming and outgoing connections are blocked in the firewall?

Tags: debian, iptables, vps, ping, ufw

I have DENIED both incoming and outgoing connections using `ufw` on Debian VPS. There is only one rule defined, which is to allow connection to SSH port.

`ufw` is enabled and working.

Yet I am still able to ping from my laptop to server using its IP. Why is ping still working if both incoming and outgoing connections are blocked (except SSH)?

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6995/how-to-enable-ufw-firewall-to-allow-icmp-response)

Comment: You have blocked ports. Ports are for TCP and UDP. Ping doesn't use ports.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ping is ICMP so there's no TCP/UDP connections to block or accept (and that's what you probably denied). ICMP rules are configured in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6995/how-to-enable-ufw-firewall-to-allow-icmp-response) for more information.